# opencv Ideas for obstacle avoidance - python

Tags: python, opencv

I am working on an obstacle avoidance strategy for my toy based on open-cv
I have the process down to being able to define a navigable area (ie obstacle free) See 'Win 1-2 Nav Blured'
[image]

The idea was to choose the deepest range - amounting to the highest black area
But now I am stuck when I realised this will actually pick an area that is too narrow to go through
I cant get my head around how to program for the perspective where it needs to be wide up close and
narrower the further away it gets.
So in the image with the lines I want to eliminate the spike caused by the red approach because it is too narrow.
[image: test image with approaches]

Answer (score 0):

OK I have an acceptable 1st cut solution (in case anybody else is trying this)
I messed around in excel and found that the 'width' of an acceptable trapezium can be a simple factor
of the row its on ie smaller further away - larger up close.
Now I just scan top-to-bottom, left-to-right and if I find an area less than this min width it gets erased.
You can see the two mountains on the left fail the width test so get zapped.
And for the sake of this first exercise the 'prefered' direction will be the one that takes me further
The results are shown - this will be good enough to try on my chariot.

[image: Navigable Area]  [image: Final Target]

```
    # scan top to bottom, left to right and compute the 'width' of each black stripe.
# if its too narrow - being < 0.45 times the row number then turn it to white - thus cancelling it as a navigable area
# the factor was computed in excel and represents a trapezium - narrow at the top (far away), wide at the bottom (up close)
# (1st plan) the furthest acceptable area is our target - we need, eventually, a bearing to stear
factor = 0.45
targetArea = [maxRow, minCol, maxCol]  # thats row, start-col, end-col
for row in range((minRow + 2), (maxRow - 2), 1):      
    minWidthForRow = max(int(row*factor), 40) # dont accept stupid widths - in infinite distance its the eye of a needle
    inClearSpace = 0
    widthCount = 0
    startCol = minCol
    endCol = maxCol
    for col in range (minCol, maxCol, 1):  #for the width of image array
        if inClearSpace == 0 :
            if NavigableArea[row, col] == Grayscale_black:   #check to see if the pixel is black(0) which indicates start of clear-space
                inClearSpace = 1                             # turn counting mode on
                startCol = col                               # remember where it started
        else:                                                # in inClearSpace 
            if NavigableArea[row, col] != Grayscale_black:   # if the next pixel has gone to white we are the end of the clearspace
                endCol = col                                 #so see if it was wide enough
                if (endCol - startCol) <= minWidthForRow :   # too narrow so zap it 
                    NavigableArea[row, startCol:endCol] = Grayscale_white
                else:                                       # else: leave it alone its valid, see if its our best guess yet
                    if row < targetArea [0] :
                        targetArea [0] = row
                        targetArea [1] = startCol
                        targetArea [2] = endCol
                    elif row == targetArea [0] and ((endCol - startCol) > (targetArea [2] - targetArea [1] )) : # same row but wider target
                        targetArea [1] = startCol
                        targetArea [2] = endCol
                inClearSpace = 0                             # regardless, say we are out of ClearSpace
# If we found something draw a line from middle of target to 'base' to prove which way we are going
if targetArea [0] != maxRow:  # not its start value
    # I think lines use x,y - backwards from the row,col we have been using ie x=col and y=row
    NavigableAreaColor = cv2.cvtColor(NavigableArea,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
    fromx = int(targetArea[1] + ((targetArea[2] - targetArea[1]) / 2))  # start col + half width
    fromy = int(targetArea [0])
    tox = int(maxCol / 2)        # middle of the array
    toy = int(maxRow)            # last line
    cv2.line(NavigableAreaColor, (fromx, fromy), (tox, toy), (0,0,255),2)
    #                              From           to        colour   thichness
# show result
tempNavigableArea2 = NavigableArea.copy()
cv2.imshow('Win 4-4', tempNavigableArea2)
cv2.imshow('Win 4-5', NavigableAreaColor)
```